# Export base64 image to Excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, excel

I'm exporting my html table to excel using following js code, but in excel file it shows cross mark. images are sent in base64 format from the server.

```js
exportAsXLSX(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    this.todaysDate = new Date();
    filename='Absent-Report'+this.datePipe.transform(this.todaysDate,"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
  }
```